# Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. warning message

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

In my case I have two apps using camera. Till now everything was OK. Since few days (I've updated device to 9.3 and Xcode to 7.3) in both apps I got warning "Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot."
To be precisely my apps still working properly, I can take photo but warning message appears.
Below I put sample code I use to capture pictures.
Can someone tell me is it code problem or xcode/ios bug ?
And how it impact to appStore submision process.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

@IBAction func cameraButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera) {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera;
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}


func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
    imageView.image = image
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);
}


func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

}

Comment: I've seen this warning in a couple of other cases, both modally presented views, and have solved the problem. Let me know if you'd still like an answer, and maybe I can help.

Answer (score 0):

If your sample code is accurate, then this looks like an iOS bug/warning leaking from UIKit internals to me. No where in your code are you explicitly snapshotting a view.